# Parsing with Goutte - how to target an element after one containing a text string

Tags: php, parsing, goutte, domcrawler

I am using https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte to parse and extract data and I am doing well...

But now I stumbled upon a slightly unfriendly spot:

```
<tr>
<th>Website:</th>
<td>
    <a href="http://www.adres.com" target="_blank">http://www.adres.com</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to get text from a `td` element which immediately follows a `th` element which contains a specific string, `Website:` in this case.

My php looks like this:

```
$client3 = new \Goutte\Client();
$crawler3 = $client3->request('GET', $supplierurl . 'contactinfo.html');

if($crawler3->filter('th:contains("+Website+") + td a')->count() > 0) {
    $parsed_company_website_url = $crawler3->filter('th:contains("Website:") + td')->text();
} else {
    $parsed_company_website_url = null;
}
return $parsed_company_website_url;
```

#### Problem

My code doesn't work.

My attempts

- I tried using both `"+Website+"` and `"Website:"`
- I tried to do some smart targeting by counting rows of the table, but each DB entry on the target site arranges items differently, no reliable pattern.

#### TO DO

Make the script extract the text from a

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `contains()` is a jquery feature and not a css selector. With css, you may inspect attribute value but not the text node inside a markup.

So, in your case, I would use xpath selector, especially: `following-sibling` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29380551/1997849)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your question.

The table in php_notes.php file.

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
    <a href="">xyz</a>
    <a href="">abc</a>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <th>Website:</th>
    <td>
        <a href="http://www.adres.com" target="_blank">http://www.adres.com</a>
    </td>
    <th>Website:abc</th>
    <td>
        <a href="http://www.adres.com" target="_blank">http://www.ares.com</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Crawler.php finds the text in anchor tag from php_notes.php file.

```
use Weidner\Goutte\GoutteFacade;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$crawler = GoutteFacade::request('GET','http://localhost/php_notes.php');

        $table = $crawler->filter('#table'); // find the parent table 

        // find each td tag
        $tdText = $table->filter('td')->each(function ($node){

            $alike = $node->previousAll(); // calculate the elements of the same level above this 
            //element :Will return array containing the tags above this tag.

            // dump('Size of array => '.sizeof($alike));
            $elementTag = $alike->eq(0); // find the tag above this <td> tag. 

            // if the tag above this tag is a <th> tag
            if($elementTag->nodeName()=='th'){
                if($elementTag->text()=='Website:')
                {
                    $text = $node->filter('a')->text();

                    dd('Text found form td "'.$text.'"');
                }
            }

        });

        dd('Not Text Was Found From A tag');
```

You can get help regarding Symfony Crawler from here 'https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html'